"耳障りよく" What does it mean?
共通の敵がいるために会話が弾む.
根本にある保身、転嫁、偽善的な感情を、「団結」と耳障りよく言い換えているように思われた。
I understand what the sentence means. My reading is that the narrator is explaining negative emotions are replaced with 団結 so it sounds better to the hear.
But I don't understand "耳障り" is a negative word? How is the sentence divided?
根本にある保身、転嫁、偽善的な感情を emotions such as self protection etc
団結」と言い換えているように思われた are put as unity
What kind of word is 耳障りよく? As far I know only 耳障り exists?

This question is similar to: What does 耳障りのいい mean?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Prescriptively,

耳触り（みみざわり） is a non-word or a made-up word that should not be accepted. (I personally think this position is untenable at this point. It might have been debatable decades ago according to the NHK reference below though.)
耳障り（みみざわり） implies being annoyed by sound, thus is inherently negative. It's wrong if you use it positively.

Descriptively,

耳触り（みみざわり） is used similarly to 手触り（てざわり） and 肌触り（はだざわり）, for sound instead of touch. It isn't inherently negative nor positive. You can add がよい and がわるい to indicate good or bad. (And on how to parse 耳障りよく, if you omit が, you get 耳ざわりがよい > 耳ざわりよい > 耳ざわりよく.)
The above word, used neutrally, can be found written 耳障り. I think this is widely considered "wrong" even by people who accept 耳触り. But it's not a big deal because the two are homophones and look similar enough. In casual written communication, I think people recognize it as a misspelling, understand what you mean, and move on.

If you write 耳ざわり, which is not unreasonable, the distinction between 耳触り and 耳障り is more moot.
References

https://www.bunka.go.jp/prmagazine/rensai/kotoba/kotoba_004.html
https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/gimon/005.html


I would say 耳障り in your sentence is a typo for 耳触り. In my opinion, 耳障り and 耳触り should be strictly distinguished in the same way as other homophones such as 暑い/厚い or 合う/会う. The kanji 障る only means "to annoy/disturb".
耳触りが良い has now become a common set phrase meaning "pleasant to the ear", and you can easily confirm this fact by searching social media. While I regularly hear claims that 耳触り doesn't exist as a word, it's already been several decades since it came into use, and it's almost meaningless to object to its use today. Recent dictionaries often list 耳触り without any hesitation, while others point out that it's "originally incorrect" or simply ignore the existence of the word.
Interestingly, on social media, nearly half of the instances of 耳障り are used as part of the (wrong) phrase 耳障りが良い. It's unfortunate if some IME still can't correctly convert みみざわりがいい to correct kanji despite its high frequency. I personally think it would be more constructive to teach that 耳障り and 耳触り are different words, rather than ignoring the existence of 耳触り in education.
